# How to calculate the value from user input

Tags: python

Does anyone know how to calculate directly from only one user input?
for example:

```
input = 1 + 2
output = 3
```

only one input is allowed. Also, when the user enters an invalid equation such as 1 +* 2, it need to show invalid.

Comment: "I've tried all day", Please share your code, your efforts in the post [edit] and add it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow? Have you tried searching on here for similar questions? Also are you looking to support only expressions with two numbers and an operator, or more complex inputs as well?

Comment: It sound interesting. I'll try

Comment: @CrazyChucky I tried to search for a similar question on Stack Overflow but none of them is using python language. I am new to programming so I can't understand the other language. The equation is a maximum of only 2 numbers. For example: 21 + 11, -21 - -11, -21 / 11, 21 * -11/

Comment: You can search for Python questions by putting `[python]`  in your query.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluating a mathematical expression without eval() on Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38860682/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-without-eval-on-python3)

Comment: @CrazyChucky in fact, this has already been asked before : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38860682/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-without-eval-on-python3

Answer (score 3):

One of the ways is to use the `eval()` function.

```
user_input = input("Enter expression :")
try:
    print(eval(user_input))
except:
    print("Invalid expression!")
```

Example Output :

```
Enter expression : 1 + 2
>>> 3
```

But be wary of this function, as it could be dangerous to use in a few cases.

Comment: but using this, the invalid equation will still get an output with only the number

Comment: How it can be dangerous. Can you give some examples

Comment: @LynnJun, I have edited the answer now

Comment: @RishabhSemwal, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940. By *dangerous to use*, it mean that it could be misused.

Comment: if i input (--23 + 45), it will still give output

Comment: It's a genius solution. Thanks for telling me the beauty of eval() function. But still, I didn't understand how it can be misused. Can you give me a example of this

Comment: It still gives output as it evaluates `--23` as `-(-23)` which equals `23`

Comment: @RishabhSemwal, the `eval()` function evaluates any type of statement, not just mathematical expression. So, if a user enters `my_var = 12` in the input, a variable `my_var` will be created with value `12`. This can be misused if the user somehow knows the names of variables and manipulates them such that the program functionality can be hampered.

Comment: wow, its interesting. It is the beauty of the function instead of the drawback. Though it depends on the user whether he misuses it or make use of it

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I meant!

Comment: Ohh. then it should be handled carefully

Comment: wht should i do if i want (--23 + 45) be an invalid input?

Comment: Yes, it will still be a valid input.

Comment: i mean in my question paper, (--23 + 45) is an invalid value.